# Find all records with two conditions where one condition are true and other false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to find all associated records where two conditions are met. 
I'm trying this, but it doesn't work, examples:

```
  @students = @group.students
    .includes(:attendances)
    .where.not(attendances: {student_id: @ids, event_time_id: @event_id})

  @students = @group.students
    .includes(:attendances)
    .where.not(attendances: {event_time_id: @event_id})
    .where.not(attendances: {student_id: @ids})

  @students = @group.students
    .includes(:attendances)
    .where("attendances.student_id IN (?) AND NOT attendances.event_time_id = ?", @ids, @event_id)
```

I want to get all the student records that exist in group and not have attendance with `@event_id` or have not attendance at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you want (untested), not the most elegant looking code...

```
exists_fragment = "SELECT 1 FROM attendances WHERE student_id = students.id"

@group.students
  .joins(:attendance)
  .where("attendances.event_id <> ? OR NOT EXISTS(?)", @event_id, exists_fragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
  @students = @group.students.includes(:attendances)
    .where("attendances.event_time_id != ?", @event_id)
    .references(:attendances)

  @students_on = @group.students.includes(:attendances)
    .where(attendances: { event_time_id: @event_id })

  @students = @students - @students_on
```

Not sure if this is the best solution but it solves the mentioned problems

**UPDATE**
Less code version:

```
  @students = @group.students
  @students_exist =  @group.students.includes(:attendances)
    .where(attendances: { event_time_id: @event_id })
  @students = @students - @students_exist
```